# How to send data with get response from Laravel to Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, http, vuejs3

I want to send data from a backend route in **`web.php`** to a `vue component`.

Approach 1:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return 'backend data';
})->name('about');
```

This works but when I refresh the page, the `vue component` does not get rerendered.

Approach 2:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('app');
})->name('about');
```

This does refresh the `vue component` correctly but it sends the whole `blade view`.

I was hoping for something like this:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('app')->with('backend data');
})->name('about');
```

which also sends the whole `blade view` and not the `data string`.

I've defined the component route in `vue-router` as:

```
{ path: "/about", name: "about", component: About },
```

The `vue component` fetches the data with `axios`:

```
onMounted(() => {
    axios.get('/about').then(res => {state.data = res.data})
})
```

What I want is to get the data and be able to refresh the `vue component`.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return response()->json(['data'=>'backend data'],200);
})->name('about');
```

or if you want to send the view also

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return response()->view('your_view',compact('data'));
})->name('about');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried `Route::get('/about', function () {
    return response()->view('app', ['data' => 'hello world']);
})->name('about');` but it still renders the `blade view` instead of the `data` in the frontend

Comment: I'm trying to send the `blade view` together with `data` because else when I refresh the page, the `vue component` does not get rendered.